# When Android widget RemoteViewService gets destroyed

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-widget

I am working on `Widget` that contains `ListView` as collections. I have created the concrete implementation of `RemoteViewService` and implement `onGetViewFactory()` method to provide `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` concrete implementation.

I set service to `RemoteView` using following code:

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction("remote_service");
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, intent);
```

I am saving List object in concrete implementation of `RemoteViewFactory`.

**Query Steps:**

- Placed widget on home screen.
- Which cause RemoteViewFactory to be created.
- Put device in sleep mode.
- Will **RemoteViewService** destorys now which caused **RemoteViewFactory**
  concrete implementation to garbage collected and hence `List<String>`
  object destorys.

Please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RemoteViewsService`, like an `AppWidgetProvider`, is not going to live forever. Your `RemoteViewsService`, in its `onGetViewFactory()` method, should return a new instance of your `RemoteViewsFactory`. Any data needed by the `RemoteViewsFactory` needs to be persistent (e.g., `SQLiteDatabase`) and retrieved as needed.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare for confirming that RemoteViewService can destroy any time by OS. I will change implementation to keep data persisted in SQLite database